# how to use react-springy-parallax

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How do I use the `scrollTo` in `react-springy-parallax`?

I'm trying to use `react-springy-parallax` in a simple portfolio page, you can click to springy parallax scroll to the next page but I want to be able to use nav links as well, here is how the app is laid out:

**App.js**

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.ref = 'parallax'
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Parallax ref={this.ref} pages={4}>

          <Parallax.Layer
            offset={0}
            speed={0.5}
            onClick={() => this.refs.parallax.scrollTo(1)}
          >
            <Nav />
            <Header />
          </Parallax.Layer>
          ...
```

So the `onClick` here just scrolls to the next page, I want to be able to say in my `Nav` component click the `About` link and it will scroll +1 so `scrollTo(1)`

Here is the nav component:

**Nav.js**

```
class Nav extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="nav">
        <ul className="links">
          <li>
            <a href="#about">About</a>
          </li>
          ...
```

I did try importing the `scrollTo` named export from `react-springy-parallax` into the nav component but got an error in the Chrome dev console saying it's not a function

I'm now trying to use a click handler:

```
class Nav extends React.Component {

  render() {
    function handleClick(e) {
      e.preventDefault()
      console.log(e)
    }
    return (
      <div className="nav">
        <ul className="links">
          <li>
            <a
              href="#"
              onClick={handleClick}
            >
              About
            </a>
          </li>
          ...
```

But I don't know how to call back to `App.js` to call the `scrollTo`

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

[logged an issue with the repo owner](https://github.com/drcmda/react-springy-parallax/issues/3) and he was kind enough to give a few pointers:

Use `contextTypes` to access the `scrollTo` method from `parallax`

In the `Nav` component use:

```
Nav.contextTypes = { parallax: React.PropTypes.object }
```

This will allow you to use the `scrollTo` method

Something like:

```
class Nav extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="nav">
        <ul className="links">
          <li>
            <a
              href=""
              onClick={this.context.parallax.scrollTo(0)}
            >
              Home
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a
              href=""
              onClick={this.context.parallax.scrollTo(1)}
            >
              About
            </a>
          </li>
```

You can also pass the function as a prop, like so:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.handleScroll = value => this.parallax && this.parallax.scrollTo(value)
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Parallax
          ref={ref => (this.parallax = ref)}
          pages={4}
        >

        <Parallax.Layer
          offset={0}
          speed={0.5}
          onClick={() => this.handleScroll(1)}
        >
          <Nav handleScroll={this.handleScroll} />
```

Then from the `Nav` component use props `onClick={() => this.props.handleScroll(PAGE)}` with PAGE being the page number you want to scroll to.